# Dependency injection in MVC, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, solid

I'm building a simple app following SOLID principles and MVC architecture. I want to parse images from server in my NetworkClass and to show them inside CollectionView in my ViewController. Here is my View Controller:

```
protocol NetworkServiceProtocol {
    func parseImages() -> [Image]
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageCollection: UICollectionView!

    private let networkService: NetworkServiceProtocol
   
    convenience init(service: NetworkServiceProtocol) {
        self.init()
        self.networkService = service
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        images = networkService!.parseImages()
    }

}
```

Here is my NetworkService class (I'll do parsing later):

```
class NetworkService: NetworkServiceProtocol {
    
    func parseImages() -> [Image] {
        return [Image]()
    }
    
}
```

The problem is that when I run this code, it crashes in `viewDidLoad()` on calling `networkService!`. I see the problem is in instantiating NetworkServiceProtocol. Where and how should I instantiate it? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You have to use this approch. Since you are using a storyboard. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41926924/14733292

Comment: Nitpicking: this is not SOLID, rather a counter example ;)

Comment: Could you explain why, please?

Comment: What I'm also gonna do is make parsing in another private func inside NetworkService, not in parseImages(). And only then pass what I've gotten into parseImages().

Comment: I see you have an IBOutlet defined. Assuming you are instantiating this vc from storyboard. In that case the init with decoder is called not the convenience init you added. This means you'll have to pass network service another way either through segue or by calling the property setter after instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are initializing your `ViewController` from storyboard, which is using your `required init?(coder: NSCoder)` which throws `fatalError`.

In order to solve it, firstly change:

```
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            //error: networkService not initialized
            super.init(coder: coder)
        }
```

This error now is because of `networkService` class property which is not initialized through this initializer. Now in order to solve this, you may give it a default property to it in the class like, `let networkService = NetworkServiceProtocol()` and right after initialization through storyboard set it to your desired `NetworkServiceProtocol` object. (Another option is making it a optional)

**Note:** you have to remove the private access modifier in order to set it from another class. If you still want it to be private, you then have to write a setter method for it.

Comment: I can't do let networkService = NetworkServiceProtocol() because it gives the following error: "'NetworkServiceProtocol' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers"

Comment: The original post is indeed misleading. You can't instantiate a protocol, but you can initialize a class that conforms to it. In your case, it's ```NetworkService```.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't realised that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by unchecking my View Controller as Initial View Controller in Storyboard and adding the following code into my AppDelegate:

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        let storybaord = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let initialVC = storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        initialVC.networkService = NetworkService()
        
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialVC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Here, you use `NetworkServiceProtocol` as an "Interface" (aka Protocol). However, Interfaces are not _abstractions_ - well, not automatically ;)  For example, consider if the next story in the backlog requires that you now would store your images in CoreData or Realm and fetch them from there. Would you still use `NetworkServiceProtocol` for your "Image Data Provider"?  How about "ImageProvider" protocol with a more flexible to use function: `func images(with query: Query, completion: @escaping (Result<[Image], Error>) -> Void`)?

Comment: Now I see what you mean, I'll change it, thank you very much!